# How can we store additional meta data about a Git repo?

Tags: git, github, artificial-intelligence

With the growing number of microservices, and people moving around projects. It is getting difficult to find someone who supports a service.

Is it possible to put into GitHub enterprise some metadata and who the owners are and the people supporting it?

AI and other knowledge management tools such as a bot can find or index the info so it can answer.

Right now I get to the right people by word of mouth. Takes too long.

I also do not want to trigger builds.

Any ideas?

Comment: Aside from adding a readme?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by having some sort of standard metadata file and then having a bot crawl look in each repo and aggregate the data.  This bot essentially builds a catalog of every service.

We use this approach at my current employer, where we include data about the service, its name, the team that owns it, its importance (critical, less critical, nice to have), and various other metadata.  We happen to store it in a YAML file, but other options are possible.  We specifically allow a file to declare multiple services, since sometimes a repository will necessarily need to host more than one logical service.

As to getting this data into the repository, we relied on people to add this data.  We now require up-to-date data before deploying any service via a CI check, which means that it is less likely to be accidentally missing.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to put into GitHub enterprise some metadata

Yes, it is now possible (Q1 2024)

> ### [Repository Custom Properties GA and Ruleset Improvements](https://github.blog/changelog/2024-02-14-repository-custom-properties-ga-and-ruleset-improvements) (Feb. 2024)
>
> https://github.com/github/release-assets/assets/185122/0c49fbdf-7f97-4019-9828-a32ea7524c9a -- repository custom properties banner image
>
> We’re excited to announce the general availability of Repository Custom Properties, a major enhancement to how repositories are managed and classified across GitHub organizations.
>
> Properties offer a flexible way to add meaningful metadata to your repositories that simplifies repository classification, enhances discoverability, and seamlessly integrates with rulesets.
>
> [Check out this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0CYdcqZxyQ) from our own [Jon Peck](https://github.com/peckjon) for a walk through of a common scenario.
>
> [Learn more about managing custom properties for your organization](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/organizations/managing-organization-settings/managing-custom-properties-for-repositories-in-your-organization.md) and [managing rulesets for your organization](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/organizations/managing-organization-settings/managing-rulesets-for-repositories-in-your-organization).
>
> [Head over to community discussions for feedback](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/69914).